# better method for the condition "-or" Powershell

Tags: azure, powershell, resources

I have this code that the truth looks very tangled and I would like to make it more beautiful in sight

`(Get-AzResource | Where {($_.tags.tag1-eq $null) -or ($_.tags.tag2-eq $null) -or ($_.tags.tag3-eq $null) -or ($_.tags.tag4-eq $null) -or ($_.tags.tag5-eq "") -or ($_.tags.tag6-eq "") -or ($_.tags.tag7-eq "")}`

This code fulfills the function of finding resources that do not have certain tags and that are empty, but the problem is that I leave an "-or" can I make it more beautiful in some way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`-contains` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#-contains-and--notcontains):

```bash
Get-AzResource | Where-Object {
  ($_.tags.tag1, $_.tags.tag2, $_.tags.tag3, $_.tags.tag4 -contains $null) -or
  ($_.tags.tag5, $_.tags.tag6, $_.tags.tag7 -contains '')
}
```

<sup>Note: The `(...)` around the `-contains` operations aren't strictly necessary, given the relative [operator precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operator_Precedence) of `-contains` and `-or`.</sup>